# Binary search on an ordered linked list

Tags: java, binary-search

I need some help adding a binary search method to an ordered linked list. Here's the code that I have so far but I'm stuck on this part.  I'm confused on how to take the values added with the insert method and then search through it and then say what position the element is at. Here's the program I have thus far:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

class List {
    public List next;
    public List previous;
    public long data;

    public Link(long d) {
        data = d;
    }

    public void displayLink() {
        System.out.print(data + " ");
    }
}

class OLinkList {

    private LinkedList first;
    private LinkedList last;

    public OLinkList() {
        first = null;
        last = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    public void insert(long num) {
        List newLink = new List(num);

        if (first == null) {
            first = newLink;
            last = newLink;
        } else {
            last.next = newLink;
            last = newLink;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I have an idea of how the binary search works.  How can I take something like this and apply it to the code I have?

```
public int binarySearch(int[] a, int x) {
      int low = 0;
      int high = a.length - 1;
      while (low <= high) {
         int mid = (low + high)/2;
         if (a[mid] == x) return mid;
         else if (a[mid] < x) low = mid + 1;
         else high = mid - 1;
      }
      return -1;
   }
```

Comment: Note that binary search requires random access to arbitrary elements to be efficient. That's not the case in a linked list.

Comment: After taking Joeys advice to your heart converting your List to an array (using the .toArray LinkedList Method). Use the default Java binarySearch Method Arrays.binarySearch (see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

Note:
Since calling toArray on a list takes O(n) this makes only sense, when doing multiple querys afterwards.

Comment: i don't understand how your linkedlist is ordered

Answer (score 0):

It would be better for you to either use an array or using or implementing your own TreeSet Class.  With an array you would be able to use your algorithm that you already have a little better.